# AJAX user registration and JSON returned

Tags: ajax, registration

I am using business logic plugin to tap into save user event and create some profile field values.

```
public function init(){
    parent::init();

    craft()->on('users.saveUser', function(Event $event) {

    }
}
```

On save user returns a success object.
I want to return more user profile data to the page on success.

In the save User function I have tried:

```
 if (craft()->request->isAjaxRequest())
 {
     $return = array(
         'success' => true,
         'errorCode' => 1,
         'uid' => $user->id,
         'urn' => $URN
     );

     return json_encode($return);
 }
```

but I still get the usual response of success and user id.
How do i get a thank you 'page' into the process so I can feedback to the user?

Comment: That event you're using allows you do run code when a user is saved/updated, whether that be in the front-end or in the Control Panel. Are you updating the user on the front-end?

Comment: Its incomplete. Its front end registration and code contains:   if (craft()->request->isSiteRequest()) {} 
and 
   if ($event->params['isNewUser']) {

Comment: if you're doing front-end, just submit to the saveUser endpoint in the craftcms docs for registration w/ a redirect hidden input set, once it redirects to the place you set it to, you can display the user's info there, using the currentUser object, for example: currentUser.email, etc.

Comment: Its an ajax user registration.....

Comment: One option is to hack the UsersController.php file, around line 1060 to include additional data on the return.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of listening to the `onSaveUser` event, I'd update my user save form on the front-end to point to a controller's action in my plugin.

You can run similar logic to what Craft's `UsersController->actionSaveUser()` is doing and return any custom JSON encoded data you want back to your template.